# Ajax Django simple checkbox action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, checkbox

I have a checkbox for every row of a table. My goal is checking/unchecking the checkbox and update the database in my view.py. Sorry for this simple question but I'm learning Ajax from few day and it is still an unexplored world. This is my code:

```
HTML
... 
<table>
      ...
      <tr><td>       
    <form action="mytemplate.html" method="GET" id="myform">{% csrf_token %}
        <input class="chktest" name="test" type="checkbox" value= "{{number}}">                                                                                                                                                                         
    </form>
      </td></tr>
      <tr><td>               
     <form action="mytemplate.html" method="GET" id="myform">{% csrf_token %}
        <input class="chktest" name="test" type="checkbox" value= "{{number}}">                                                                                                                                                                         
     </form>
     </td></tr>
     ...   
 </table>

**JQUERY**

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {           
        $('table tr td .chktest').click(function() {                           
                $.ajax({ 
                    data: $(this).serialize(), 
                    type: $(this).attr('method'), 
                    url: $(this).attr('action'), 
                    success: function(response) { 
                        // on success..
                    },
                    error: function(e, x, r) { 
                       // on error...                           
                    }
                }); 
            return false;

        }); 
    });
    </script>     

 **MYVIEW.PY**
 ...
 if request.is_ajax():        
    number = request.GET['number']        
    for obj in tab_company.objects.filter(id_number=number):
           obj.update(check=not obj.check)
    message = "Hello!"  
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))
```

In this way when I click the first time on checkbox I get the right number for every row. If I check another time on the same checkbox it doesn't return to False (unchecking). where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
tab_company.objects.filter(id_number=number).update(check=True)`
```

You set the value to True, instead of toggling it. Can you try the following:

```
for obj in tab_company.objects.filter(id_number=number):
    obj.update(check=not obj.check)
```

Comment: thanks @fluffels but this doesn't solve the problem of the checkbox that I can not make to False. That's right? I don't will reload the page..

Comment: The problem is that when you click the checkbox again it doesn't untick?

Comment: Maybe it's becasue you override the click event for all of this different elements? What happens if you only put .chktest in the $ selector?